# Lookup/Search option on Json data in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby-on-rails-5

I am working on JSON data with my rails app. I am trying to add a lookup search for the name column in the JSON data. Is there any gem or any useful resource which can be helpful in achieving this?

```
data = [
  {
    "Name":"Jackie",
    "Level":"Initial",
  },
  {
    "Name":"Shaun",
    "Level":"Expert",

  }
]
```

Comment: There's `Array#find` or `Array#detect`.  `json_data.find { |h| h['Name'].eql?('Jackie') }`

Comment: Do you want to return all matched data or only the first one?

Comment: @MikeHeft you need to parse JSON at first

Comment: @Vasilisa only the matched

Comment: @Vasilisa sorry I took that as assumed :D

Answer (score 0):

If you're getting data in JSON format you need to parse it at first. After it use `filter` method (alias for `select`) from Enumerable module to get only needed parts.

```
experts = JSON.parse(data).filter{ |entry| entry['Level'] == 'Expert' }
```

You get new array with matched data

```
[{"Name"=>"Shaun", "Level"=>"Expert"}]
```